# Selenium can find link element, but .get_attribute('href') returning None

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium I am attempting to get the href attribute from a link on a page. I double checked my XPATH in Chrome dev console, and my script can locate the link and works when I .click() it, but I cannot seem to pull the URL string using .get_attribute('href'). I've tried several variations and they all simply returns None (or don't return anything at all, as if Selenium can't find the element, but no error)

some of my code attempts:

```
x = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='app-mount']/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a"))).get_attribute('href')
```

```
x = ec.find_element((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='app-mount']/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[contains(@href, 'steamcommunity']")).get_attribute('href')
```

```
x = ec.find_element((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='app-mount']/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/following-sibling::a")).get_attribute('href')
```

The element (not full page):

```
<a class="anchor-1X4H4q anchorUnderlineOnHover-wiZFZ_" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198037294606" rel="noreferrer noopener" target="_blank" role="button" tabindex="0"><svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" width="24" height="24" class="connectedAccountOpenIcon-3i81Tz right-1dJ0yM" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><polygon fill="currentColor" fill-rule="nonzero" points="13 20 11 20 11 8 5.5 13.5 4.08 12.08 12 4.16 19.92 12.08 18.5 13.5 13 8"></polygon></svg></a>
```

Element XPATH from Chrome:
//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a

Full XPATH from Chrome:
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a

Comment: What is the error you see on the console? Can you share the URL if it can be accessed in public?

Comment: Certainly. The URL in question is discord.com/channels/@me, however in my case it's a redirect of discordapp.com/users/{userid} where userid is a Discord user id. Prior to the redirect I use Selenium to login to Discord, which then loads the discord.com/channels/@me. This page has a modal that displays the user's (from userid) profile. Within the profile is a link to the user's connected Steam account. Using selenium find by XPATH I can click the link, but I can't figure out how to get the href attribute